# Значение(,) равное

Tags: запятая

Нужна ли запятая в следующих случаях: "присвоим переменной значение(,) равное 1", "при n(,) равном 5"?

Answer (score 5):

Нужна в обоих случаях. Постпозитивное распостраненное определение обособляется.

- Марк, Господь с Вами, объясните, где здесь подлежащее? Я не вижу. Вижу определенно-личное предложение с двумя дополнениями, из которых одно ("значение") имеет распространенное определение в постпозиции.
  UPD
- Думается мне, судари мои и сударыни, математики грешат в этом вопросе противу русской грамматики по причинам отнюдь не логическим, как они об этом говорить с жаром, пылом и апломбом приобыкши, но психологическим: ведь для ума, по складу своему математического, обороты словесные в роде "значение, равное...", "величина, равная" и проч., только лишь словесное обличие знака "=" собой являют. Знак же сей в построениях математических неделим и прост, в роде атома, а потому ум, сим атомом оперировать привыкший, членению его, хотя грамматическому, невольно (и изобретательно весьма) противится...

Comment: Вот и я так всегда считала, а тут начали говорить что-то о "несамостоятельности" слова "значение", которое без цифры не несёт смысла, и ненужности запятой на основании этого...

Comment: Именно так. Ссылки - в моем ответе.

Comment: >Думается мне, судари мои и сударыни,  
  
Гы... Болѣе забавно, чѣмъ обстоятельно, но ужъ больно рѣчь хороша. 
Только ея и по старой орθографiи писать надобно.

Comment: Увы, с прискорбием нелицемерным и стыдом непритворным признаться должен,что по старой офографии хоть буквы разбирать кой-как и навыкши, да  в художестве письменном безграмотен есмь, то есть совершенно.

Comment: А зачѣмъ тогда "въ родѣ" пишѣте раздѣльно?
*Какъ спецiально слова с ятем идутъ. Я не подбиралъ. )))*

Это только до Грота такъ писали, потомъ уже - вродѣ.

Answer (score 4):

В математическом языке пунктуация такая же, как и в лингвистике. Запятые нужны в соответствии с правилами русской пунктуации, о которых сказал mueller, вот похожая фраза с математического сайта:" 1.Присвойте переменной ORIGIN значение, равное 1." 
  http://exponenta.ru/educat/systemat/kazah/matecon/1_1.asp
    А "Грамота" сама путается: то так ответит, то так. Что значит "определяемое слово само по себе не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении"? Смысл-"цифровое значение". Если б не было слова "равный", не было б и запятой (присвоим переменной значение 1", но оно есть, значит, есть и оборот, который следует выделить. Когда  не было ЕГЭ, на экзамене по математике медалистам снижали оценку за отсутствие нужных запятых, хотя это к математике не относится, говорили:это нарушение логики мышления, нет её-нет отличных знаний математики. Помню, я ходила и расставляла им запятые.(украдкой)

Comment: >В математическом языке пунктуация такая же, как и в лингвистике  
  
Это не так. Т.е. основополагающие вещи, конечно, совпадают, а вот что касается пограничных, опциональных или т.н. "авторских" случаев, то тут складываются определенные школы. В данном случае смысл самого слова "значение" в математике несколько отличается от обычного "это имеет значение". Отсюда и особое понимание синтаксиса/семантиеи, которое отражается на пунктуации.

Comment: Не видела такого. Лексическое значение терминов - да, а в пунктуации разницы не видела ни разу. На "Ответах" были спорные ситуации, там один математик со мной спорил, так потом спрашивающий мне на почту прислал письмо и сказал, что зря он не послушал меня и ответил по-другому - там оказалась ошибка, снизили оценку.

Comment: >Смысл-"цифровое значение"  
  
Нет такого смысла. Есть смысл "переменная *равна* пяти". есть такое понятие "метаматематика", используемое в одним из значений как термин в описании самого математического языка. Так вот  у переменной есть имя (N, Сi, XXX) и значение (0, 5, 6+4i). Любая перемнная имеет какое-то значение или принимает его в какой-то точке.  

>вот похожая фраза с математического сайта  
     
На сайтах, пишут и так и эдак. Увы, я учился, когда слова "сайт" в русском даже в проекте не было. Посмотрю в старых учебниках.

Comment: >а в пунктуации разницы не видела ни разу  
  
Зато я сталкивался, когда мне корректоры одной запятой весть текст гробили. ))) Правда все это было давно и в прошлой жизни. Увы, научить-то меня научили писать правильно (как им казалось), а вот со сколько-нибудь  серьезной математикой все равно пришлось завязать, ибо все равно не понимали ))) 

>На "Ответах" были спорные ситуации...
  
Ну знаете, со мной тоже много кто спорил ))) Ссылочкой не побалуете, о чем вообще там речь шла?

Кстати, давайте DocentI спросим, у неё-то математические учебники, не на сайтах писаные, наверняка под рукой.

Comment: "Фраза "переменная имеет значение" бессодержательна без уточнения." - ну вот она и уточняется с помощью обособленного определения, а может уточняться с помощью придаточного предложения.Тогда тоже не нужна запятая?Вот в Википедии:" В математике переменная — это величина, характеризующаяся множеством значений, которое она может принимать".У нас тоже возможно сказать:"присвоим переменной значение,которое будет равняться 1". Запятая нужна?-нужна.Почему ж там не нужна.

Comment: А насчёт "Ответов" - разве теперь найдёшь - за 4 года  их столько было - сутки будешь искать-не найдёшь. Я однажды попыталась - надо было - не нашла нужного даже в "Поиске" по сайту.

Comment: Согласна с Людмилой. Правила пунктуации должны быть обязательными для всех . Кстати, ситуация, описанная Людмилой, и мне напомнила прежние годы.Когда в школе случались золотые медалисты, математики бегали к нам за уточнением, так ли расставлены знаки, по правилам ли. Потому что краевая медальная комиссия снижала отметки за ошибки в пунктуации и орфографии.  Соответственно, медаль ребенок уже не получал. Правда, уже не помню, встречался ли именно такой случай.

Comment: Понимаете, все это очень здорово - помогать безграмотным математикам, но не стоит палку перегибать. Есть случаи, когда вы (ну или наша система образования) оказываете медвежью услугу. Случай с "значение(,) равное нулю" - из той самой серии. Вы смысл искажаете этой запятой - и ту самую логику мышления именно что нарушаете. Ну нет в математике (на том уровне, что школьникам даётся) самостоятельного понятия "значение". Только "значение равное".  
И ещё. Не надо из одного случая мировую проблему раздувать. Реально таких "спорных" написаний очень немного, я что-то больше и припомнить не могу.

Comment: >Реально таких "спорных" написаний очень немного, я что-то больше и припомнить не могу.

Ещё выражение "по данным", которое обособляется в быту (*по данным ТАСС, ...*), но не обособляют в науке (*"Возраст" древесины по данным радиоуглеродного анализа составил 45 000 лет, а ткани - 10 000 лет*). 

Также математики используют составной союз "такой что" (*Предположим еще, что линии С0 и С задаются с помощью однозначных функций y=y0(x) и y=y(x), **таких что** |y0'(x)| и |y'(x)| не превосходят положительной константы c*), однако формально союза "такой что" нет и слова должны быть разделены запятой

Comment: По данным ТАСС в одних ситуациях не обособляется, в других обособляется. Надо чувствовать логику фразы.В русском языке союз "такие как" тоже не разделяется перед однородными членами-это оборот: "мы видим многие..., такие как..."

Comment: @Людмила, союз "такой что", а не "такой как".

Answer (score 2):

В математизированных текстах эти запятые обычно не ставятся именно на основании того, что определяемое слово само по себе не выражает нужного значения и с точки зрения семантики является вспомогательным по отношению к определяющему.

//====
Вопрос № 249292
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в следующем выражении:
"эта величина имеет значение, равное пяти" ?
благодарю за помощь
GIOSHA
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Запятая не нужна: определяемое слово само по себе не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении
//====

Можете посмотрить еще обсуждение здесь:  
http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1541
Правда, там совсем запутали вопрос, но логику тех и других понять можно.
Я - за то, что запятой не надо.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько знаю, математики зачастую произносят "один" в именительном,  а не дательном падеже. Соответственно, *значение равное один*, это тоже самое, что *должность равная "министр (министерскую)"*. Т.е. тут получается не одно развернутое определение, а два простых, поэтому как раз в первом случае легко можно отбросить любое определение с сохранением смысла, а во вторм - уже так не получится. Ср. *значение один, значение равное*, **но**, *эн равном, эн пяти*.

Думаю разночтения в знаках препинания между лингвистами и математиками как раз из-за этого.

Comment: >математики зачастую произносят "один" в именительном, а не дательном падеже.  
  
Это так. Более того, такое произношение усиливается при в серьёзных разделах: "равно иксу" я вряд ли скажу, только "равно икс". Дальнейших рассуждений я не понял...

Comment: @behemothus, я имею в виду, что "один" в именительном падеже не сообразует словосочетание с "равное". "Один" и "равное" служат определением слова "значение", но не согласуются между собой, что необходимо для развёрнутого определения. *Значение является равным и один.*

Ср. *Мы прибывали к городу немецкому Берлин*, но *Мы прибывали к городу, немецкому Берлину*.

Comment: >я имею в виду, что "один" в именительном падеже не сообразует словосочетание с "равное".   
  
Это-то я понял, хотя само по себе утверждение спорное. Скорее всего просто счатают математические величины несклоняемыми, как буквы латинского алфавита.  
Но допустим, что вы все-таки правы. Что дальше-то?  
Как из всего этого сделать какой-то вывод в отношении двух(!) простых  определений?

Comment: Я-то исхожу, если очень примитивно излагать, из следуюшего. 
"При температуре больше нуля" - запятая нужна? Нет.
"При значении больше нуля" - запятая нужна? Нет.
"При температуре больше или равной нулю" - нужна?
"При значении больше или равном нулю" - нужна?
Так зачем же она в простом случае "При значении равном нулю"?
А для математика эти фразы равнозначны абсолютно равнозначны по форме.

Comment: >Как из всего этого сделать какой-то вывод в отношении двух(!) простых определений?

@behemothus, так обособлять предлагают как раз "распространённое определение", два определения с разными значениями не обособляются (ср. *длинная широкая дорога*).

А запятая в приведённых вами примерах не ставится, потому что "больше (или равно)" как раз не возможно соотнести с "нулю" (*больше нул**я**)*. Ср. *прибыли к городу славному Москве*, запятая не ставится, но *прибыли к городу(,) славному(,) Ижевску*, запятая указывает на то, к чему относится опредедение "славному".